# putting the chosen value in a text field

Tags: ios, uipickerview

when the user select an item in a pickerView and press OK button, i have to put the selected item in a UITextField, so in the IBAction of the OK button what should i put please ? thx in advance :)
**this is my OK button code :**

```
-(IBAction)okButton{
    [billTotal setText:@"Hi"];//the text field name is billTotal, this didn't work :(

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 480);
    pickerView.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
...
NSInteger selectedRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
billTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", selectedRow];
...
```

> This didn't work

Check if your outlet connected to text field, and that "okButton" selector is called

Comment: if you want to place value of selected row, i.e. title of row, you should receive this title from array or what are you using to store them, by selectedRow index

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, i try to implement your code, however, every item i select show me 0 in the UITextField, like it doesn't transmiss the entire value of the picker :(

Comment: the array name is pickerViewArray

Comment: @Malek, check that your picker outlet is connected to UIPickerView, otherwise you always will receive 0. To receive your item from array use [pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];

Comment: Hi, everything works great, only one thing, it display always the first item in the picker even if i choose the last one, can you please help me there ?? thx

Comment: @Malek, have you checked outlet connection?

Comment: YES, the delegate and the datasource are connected to the file owner, also the picker is connected to the outlet :)

Comment: insert in your okButton selector following line `NSLog(@"picker: %@, slectedRow: %d, item: %@"`, picker, [picker selectedRowInComponent], [pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent]]);` Then run application on simualtor, select some row, press your OK button, then look at console log (Shift+Cmd+Y) and post there what you see (something like "picker:<eb163445> selectedRow: 1, item: 'My item'")